# how to get label id in asp.net for using in jquery,?

Tags: asp.net

I am not getting label id in jquery code , i use anchor tag , it is working , the text changes to today's date on page load , but when i apply it to label control of asp.net , it doesn't work , search may pages on web , but doesn't get proper solution how to change text of label using java script  or jquery , is here anybody can solve it.

### here is the code to look out .

```
  <div>
    <div>
        <table class="foruploadtable">

            <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="foruploadtabletitle" >Share From Here .</span>    
                   <hr />

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Max Size 1MB :</td><td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" ToolTip="Select File By Clicking Browse ." CssClass="foruploadtableupload"  runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" CssClass="foruploadtablebutton"  ToolTip="Click Here To Upload." Text="Upload." OnClick="b1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <a id="me">hello</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var say = $('#me').text();
         var date = new Date();
         $('#me').text(date.getDate());
       $('#Label1').text(date.getDate());
        // alert(date.getDate());
     });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

change label add attribute **ClientIDMode="Static"**

```
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
$('#Label1').text(date.getDate());
```

or

```
$('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text(date.getDate());
```

Comment: that was kick-ass,  it works great , both code works , salute buddy, thanks ...........................

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var say = $('#me').text();
         var date = new Date();
         $('#me').text(date.getDate());
         $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text(date.getDate());
        // alert(date.getDate());
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your page does not have master page. If it is so then you can use Client ID as below

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var say = $('#me').text();
     var date = new Date();
     $('#me').text(date.getDate());
   $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text(date.getDate());
    // alert(date.getDate());
 });
```

Comment: i am using master page .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text(date.getDate());
```

This helps to grab the id generated by ASP.Net for the id parameter..

Comment: Great, just a bit about why this happened--> when using master page ASP.Net concatenates the local ID with master page content ID (which you can see by checking the source html file), we are using the this code block to catch the final id... Cheers..